# What is the easiest way to create a secured network client in Linux (C) without any external libraries?

Tags: c, linux, cryptography

As i said, i want to create a secured network connection (TSL/QUIC/...) in C for Linux. Is there a easy way to create that directly based on the linux standard libraries without OpenSSL or other external dependencies?

I want to use it on various linux distributions where OpenSSL and other libraries might not be available. I figured out that there is a "linux/tls.h" but i could not figure out how encrypt traffic.

Comment: You could bundle openssl with your own source and always compile it. That way you don't depend on it existing in a distrubition.

Comment: But doesn't openssl itself need a few other dependencies? And those dependencies again need some other dependencies and so on?

Comment: No. OpenSSL is a stand-alone library. It's a large, and complex one, but it's stand-alone. That said, see https://docs.kernel.org/networking/tls.html  (but it's fairly low-level)

Comment: Ok thanks! I tried the Kernel Docs, but it didn't quite work out for me. Did i understand right, the tls support for the kernel only provides the symmetric encryption, the key exchange needs to be implemented manually?
Further the symmetric encryption didn't work too, but i think i should open a new question for that